# Pegar trecho de uma string entre dois caracteres

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho uma informação que preciso que vem no seguinte formato:

```
<http://informacaoquepreciso.com.br> "rel"="next"
```

Neste caso o que preciso pegar somente o texto que está dentro dos `< >`, existe alguma função pronta para pegar este tipo de informação? Consegui fazer usando o `replace`.

Comment: Não existe função pronta para isso. Aliás, pode até existir, em alguma biblioteca de terceiros. Na biblioteca padrão, decerto não. De modo geral, você sempre terá que utilizar um conjunto de procedimentos para recuperar a informação que quer.

Comment: Obrigado Felipe, so a titulo de informação esta informação que estou pegando e o retorno de paginaçao de uma requisição que estou consumindo, e para buscar a proxima pagina tenho que pegar a url que esta dentro do <>. se tiver alguma dica.

Comment: Trivialmente, pode fazer assim (assumindo que a string sempre tenha o formato da pergunta, claro): `str[1:str.index('>')]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma expressão regular:

```
import re

texto = '<http://informacaoquepreciso.com.br> "rel"="next"'

padrao = re.compile('<(.*?)>')
achado = padrao.match(texto)
if achado:
    print(achado.group(1))
    # Imprime http://informacaoquepreciso.com.br
```

Note que esse método não funcionará caso haja um caractere `>` na informação que você precisa, como por exemplo `<http://informacaoquepreciso>.com.br> "rel"="next"`.

Comment: Enzo show demais muito obrigado, poderia explicar um pouco  a expressão regular ?, eu ainda estou aprendendo. de qualquer forma muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem certeza que essa informação sempre vem dessa forma, você pode usar o método split.

```
texto = '<http://informacaoquepreciso.com.br> "rel"="next"'
parte_util = texto.split('>')[0][1:]]
#http://informacaoquepreciso.com.br
```

Esse método, vai dividir a string baseado no caracter que você passa e retorna um lista, sendo assim, usando o index (primeiros colchetes), você consegue pegar a parte que vem antes do '>'. E com string slice (os segundos colchetes), você recupera a string **sem** o primeiro caractere, no caso, o '<'.